# Angular 5 load directive after an event occurs

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have my **HomepageComponent** that holds a custom directive **MapDirective**, bound to the selector name **myMap**.

In **homepage.component.html**

```
  ...
  <div myMap position=??></div>
  ...
```

I would like the directive to be loaded only after I retrieved the location from my **HomepageComponent**, so that I can center my map on the user location when I display it.

This requires to wait a little bit so that I can retrieve the location using [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) async call.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Where is the code for your service call. Add a `*ngIf` and check for the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a div or other tag with condition, you can use *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="position" myMap position=??></div>
```

So you will only display position div when you resolve the promise of getposition call